# Alternating counters in Python (Fibonacci Plot)

Tags: python, fibonacci

I've been assigned a project in my computing class to do a report on some area of mathematics in LaTeX, using Python 2.7 code - I chose the Fibonacci sequence.

As part of my project I wanted to include a plot of the Fibonacci 'spiral' which is actually comprised of a series of quarter-circles of increasing radii. As such, I've tried to define a function to give a loop that returns the centres of these quarter-circles so I can create a plot. Using pen and paper I have found the centres of each quarter-circle and noticed that with each new quarter-circle there's an exchange of coordinates - ie. if n is even, the x-coordinate of the previous centre remains the x-coordinate for the nth centre; similarly, when n is odd, the y-coordinate remains the same.

My problem arises with the other coordinate. They work on an alternating pattern of + or - the (n-2)th Fibonacci number to the y-coordinate (for even n) or x-coordinate (for odd) of the previous centre.

I've created the following loop in SageMathCloud, but I think I've deduced that my counters aren't incrementing when I wanted them to:

```
def centrecoords(n):
    k = 0
    l = 1
    if fib(n) == 1:
        return tuple((0,-1))
    elif n % 2 == 0 and k % 2 == 0:
        return tuple((centrecoords(n-1)[0], centrecoords(n-1)[1] + ((-1) ** k) * fib(n - 2)))
        k += 1
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return tuple((centrecoords(n-1)[0], centrecoords(n-1)[1] + ((-1) ** k) * fib(n - 2)))
    elif n % 2 != 0 and l % 2 == 0:
        return tuple((centrecoords(n-1)[0] + ((-1) ** l) * fib(n - 2), centrecoords(n-1)[1]))
        l += 1
    else:
        return tuple((centrecoords(n-1)[0] + ((-1) ** l) * fib(n - 2), centrecoords(n-1)[1]))


cen_coords = []

for i in range(0, 21):
    cen_coords.append(centrecoords(i))

cen_coords
```

Any help in making the `k` counter increment with its `if` statement only, and the same with the `l` counter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't increase counter after `return` statement, because your program leaves function when `return` is called, most likely you should introduce `k` and `l` as parameters to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `k` and `l` are local variables. As such they are lost every time the function exits, and re-start at zero and one respectively when is called again (yes, even when it's called from itself).

Nick's code aims to store a single instance each of `k` and `l` in the top-level function, sharing them with the recursive calls.

Another reasonable approach might be to rewrite your recursion as a loop, and `yield` the sequence. This makes it trivial to keep the state of `k` and `l`, as your locals are preserved.

Or, you could re-write your function as a class method, and make `k` and `l` instance variables. This behaves similarly, with the instance storing your intermediate state between calls to `centrecoords`.

---

Apart from all of these, your code looks like it requires each call to `centrecoords` to receive the next value of `n`. So, even if you fix the state problem, this is a poor design.

I'd suggest going the generator route, and taking a single argument, the maximum value of `n`. Then you can iterate over `range(n)`, yielding each result in turn. Note also that your only recursive call is for `n-1`, which is just your previous iteration, so you can simply remember it.

---

Quick demo: I haven't tested this, or checked the corner cases ...

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def centrecoords(max_n):
    # initial values
    k = 0
    l = 1
    result=(0,-1)
    # note fib(0) == fib(1) == 1
    for n in range(2,max_n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            result = (result[0], result[1] + ((-1) ** k) * fib(n - 2))
            yield result
            if k % 2 == 0:
                k += 1
        else:
            result = (result[0] + ((-1) ** l) * fib(n - 2), result[1])
            yield result
            if l % 2 == 0:
                l += 1


cen_coords = list(centrecoords(21))
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment. Your code could look something like the one below. But please not that you might need to adjust starting values of k and l to -1 and 0 correspondingly, because k and l are incremented before recursion calls (opposite to your code which implied that first a recursion is called and only then k and l are increased).
I also deleted `tuple`, it is unnecessary in python and hard to read, to create a tuple use comma syntax, e.g.: `1, 2`.
Also n == 0 (fib(n) == 0) should be considered as special case, or you program will enter infinite recursion and crash when `centrecoords` called with `n=0`.

I have no account on SageMathCloud to test it, but it at least should fix counters increment.

```
def centrecoords(n, k=0, l=1):
    if n == 0:
        return 0, 0  # this is pure guess and most likely incorrect, but n == 0 (or fib(n) == 0 should be handled separatly)
    if fib(n) == 1:
        return 0, -1
    elif n % 2 == 0 and k % 2 == 0:
        k += 1
        return centrecoords(n-1, k, l)[0], centrecoords(n-1, k, l)[1] + ((-1) ** k) * fib(n - 2)
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return centrecoords(n-1, k, l)[0], centrecoords(n-1, k, l)[1] + ((-1) ** k) * fib(n - 2)
    elif n % 2 != 0 and l % 2 == 0:
        l += 1
        return centrecoords(n-1, k, l)[0] + ((-1) ** l) * fib(n - 2), centrecoords(n-1, k, l)[1]
    else:
        return centrecoords(n-1, k, l)[0] + ((-1) ** l) * fib(n - 2), centrecoords(n-1, k, l)[1]


cen_coords = []

for i in range(0, 21):
    cen_coords.append(centrecoords(i))

cen_coords
```